# Trouble with Angular Transpiler When Migrating SystemJS from 0.19 to 0.20

Tags: angular, typescript, systemjs

OK, here it is. I'm trying to do some pretty basic stuff with Angular 4, and am migrating some old "hello world" style code forward to latest versions of Angular. At the same time I've been moving other things, including SystemJS forward.  And suddenly, I've identified a weirdness. To start with here's my package.json that works fine:

```
{
  "name": "angular-seed",
  "description": "Seed",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "start": "live-server"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/common": "^4.3.6",
    "@angular/compiler": "^4.3.6",
    "@angular/core": "^4.3.6",
    "@angular/forms": "^4.3.6",
    "@angular/http": "^4.3.6",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "^4.3.6",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^4.3.6",
    "@angular/router": "^4.3.6",
    "core-js": "^2.4.0",
    "rxjs": "5.4.3",
    "systemjs": "^0.19.47",
    "zone.js": "^0.8.17"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "live-server": "^1.2.0",
    "typescript": "^2.1.5"
  }
}
```

Using this, on a basic sort of Hello World sample, I end up with the following.

[image: Transpiler Loads Fine]

However, if I simply upgrade my SystemJS reference from "^0.19.47" to "^0.20.18" and run an "npm update" to get the updates:

```
{
  "name": "angular-seed",
  "description": "Seed",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "start": "live-server"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/common": "^4.3.6",
    "@angular/compiler": "^4.3.6",
    "@angular/core": "^4.3.6",
    "@angular/forms": "^4.3.6",
    "@angular/http": "^4.3.6",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "^4.3.6",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^4.3.6",
    "@angular/router": "^4.3.6",
    "core-js": "^2.4.0",
    "rxjs": "5.4.3",
    "systemjs": "^0.20.18", // I AM THE ONLY THING THAT CHANGED!
    "zone.js": "^0.8.17"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "live-server": "^1.2.0",
    "typescript": "^2.1.5"
  }
}
```

I now end up with the Typescript transpiler failing to load, like this:

[image]

Thoughts?

[Edit] Should have added this initially. Here's my systemjs.config.js, which maybe involved in this:

```
System.config({
    transpiler: 'typescript',
    typescriptOptions: {emitDecoratorMetadata: true},
    map: {
      '@angular': 'node_modules/@angular',
      'rxjs'    : 'node_modules/rxjs'
    },
    paths: {
      'node_modules/@angular/*': 'node_modules/@angular/*/bundles'
    },
    meta: {
      '@angular/*': {'format': 'cjs'}
    },
    packages: {
      'app'                              : {main: 'main', defaultExtension: 'ts'},
      'rxjs'                             : {main: 'Rx'},
      '@angular/core'                    : {main: 'core.umd.min.js'},
      '@angular/common'                  : {main: 'common.umd.min.js'},
      '@angular/compiler'                : {main: 'compiler.umd.min.js'},
      '@angular/platform-browser'        : {main: 'platform-browser.umd.min.js'},
      '@angular/platform-browser-dynamic': {main: 'platform-browser-dynamic.umd.min.js'}
    }
});
```

[Edit 2] Adding some progress(?)

OK, so going down the rabbit hole that SystemJS 0.20 requires changes to using a plug-in for transpilation, I've "npm install(ed) plugin-typescript" and edited my systemjs.config.js to look like this now:

```
System.config({
    // CHANGED transpiler from 'typescript' TO 'plugin-typescript' TO 
    // transpiler: 'typescript',
    transpiler: 'plugin-typescript',
    typescriptOptions: {emitDecoratorMetadata: true, experimentalDecorators: true}, // CHANGED to add experimentalDecorators since after the transpiler started working, it complained that I couldn't have emitDecoratorMetadata without experimentalDecorators set to true as well...
    map: {
      '@angular': 'node_modules/@angular',
      'rxjs'    : 'node_modules/rxjs',

      // ADDED these to support SystemJS 0.20 and Typescript Transpiler
      "plugin-typescript": "node_modules/plugin-typescript/lib/",
      "typescript": "node_modules/typescript/"

    },
    paths: {
      'node_modules/@angular/*': 'node_modules/@angular/*/bundles'
    },
    meta: {
      '@angular/*': {'format': 'cjs'}
    },
    packages: {
      'app'                              : {main: 'main', defaultExtension: 'ts'},
      'rxjs'                             : {main: 'Rx'},
      '@angular/core'                    : {main: 'core.umd.min.js'},
      '@angular/common'                  : {main: 'common.umd.min.js'},
      '@angular/compiler'                : {main: 'compiler.umd.min.js'},
      '@angular/platform-browser'        : {main: 'platform-browser.umd.min.js'},
      '@angular/platform-browser-dynamic': {main: 'platform-browser-dynamic.umd.min.js'},

      // ADDED THESE TO SUPPORT SystemJS 0.20 and Typescript Transpiler
      "plugin-typescript": {
        "main": "plugin.js"
      },
      "typescript": {
          "main": "lib/typescript.js",
          "meta": {
              "lib/typescript.js": {
                  "exports": "ts"
              }
          }
      }

    }
});
```

Now, it looks like the transpiler is kicking in, but I've got a new problem - the pathing looks like it changed as well.  Here's the latest screen shot:

[image: SystemJS 0.20 with Transpiler Using plugin-typescript but paths now sadness]

[Edit 3] Oh, for crying out loud...

https://github.com/systemjs/systemjs/issues/1039 So, SystemJS 0.20 deprecated path support. That's obviously my latest problem.  I'll work on updating my config for the new, non-wildcard enabled SystemJS. :/

RANT ON.
This is really, really frustrating. I've now spent basically a full day trying to simply move from 0.19 to 0.20 of SystemJS which seems to pretty much not give a crap about any sort of backward compatibility. By way of comparison, I've gone from Angular 2.0.0 to 4.3.6 with zero problems, in the same project.
RANT OFF.

Comment: Oh, interesting. I think this from the 0.20.0 release notes of SystemJS might be my issue - digging into it now:

"Default transpiler loading is removed. It is no longer possible to transpile sources without configuring one of the transpiler plugins."

Comment: This looks promising: https://www.npmjs.com/package/plugin-typescript